# Overriding a method of a gem module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

I need to override method "email_to_name" of gem "omnicontacts" as it doesn't work with ruby 1.8.7.
I have error for named regex in this method

```
lib/omnicontacts/parse_utils.rb:32: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<first>[a-z|A-Z]+)[\.|_](?<last>[a-z|A-Z]+)/ (SyntaxError)
```

This method located in module ParseUtils

```
module OmniContacts
  module ParseUtils
    def email_to_name username_or_email
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Then it require in other module

```
require "omnicontacts/parse_utils"
require "omnicontacts/middleware/oauth2"
require "json"

module OmniContacts
  module Importer
    class Gmail < Middleware::OAuth2
      include ParseUtils
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to override this method, but it doesn't work:

```
#config/initializer/omnicontacts.rb
require "omnicontacts"

module OmniContacts
  module ParseUtils
    def email_to_name username_or_email
      p "test"
    end
  end
end

module OmniContacts
  module Importer
    class Gmail
      module ParseUtils
        def email_to_name username_or_email
          p "test"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use OmniContacts::Builder do
  importer :gmail, "test", "test", {:redirect_path => "/contacts/gmail/callback"}
  importer :yahoo, "test", "test", {:callback_path => '/contacts/yahoo/callback'}
end
```

I use rails 2 and ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Where did you put your file with monkey patch?

Comment: I put in in initializer after requiring of omnicontacts

Comment: did you restart your app?

Comment: sure, may by issue is in the exception when file "omnicontacts/parse_utils" included in the gem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your monkey patch is loaded after the gem? Because if it's loaded before the gem, the gem's implementation will overwrite yours.

Answer (score 0):

I added file lib/omnicontacts/parse_utils.rb to my project and it override such file from gem. It solves issue, but it seems it isn't very good solution, because of this I just forked gem and add needed changes there.